# My task isn't working of ActionHerojs

Tags: node.js, task, action, console.log

```
  exports.sayHelloAction = {
    name: 'sayHelloAction',
    description: '',
    outputExample: {},
    version: 1,
    inputs: {},
    run: function (api, data, next) {

        // Enqueue the task now, and process it ASAP
        // api.tasks.enqueue(nameOfTask, args, queue, callback)
        api.tasks.enqueue("sayHello", null, 'default', function (error, toRun) {
            next(error)
        });
    }
};
```

**and my task is like this, but when I run my task from my action y cant see the log(">>>>>>>>>>") in my console :(**

```
const sayHello = {
    name:          'sayHello',
    description:   'I say hello',
    queue:         "default",
    plugins:       [],
    pluginOptions: [],
    frequency:     1000,
    run: function(api, params, next){
        console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
        next(true);
    }
};
exports.task = sayHello
```

**versions: Nodejs: 7.7, ActionHerojs 17**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are enquing a task, not running it. You need to enable some workers on your server.

Comment: Can you gime an example Evan?

Comment: https://www.actionherojs.com/docs/core/#tasks  Just set up your server to run a worker as part of it from within config/tasks.js

Comment: Thaks Evan my task is running